# Map enum to string value with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-5

I know the Entity Framework, as of version 5, supports enums. As [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx) states:

> In Entity Framework, an enumeration can have the following underlying types:  Byte, Int16,  Int32,  Int64 , or SByte.

However, this usually results in mapping enums to numbers, which is their numerical order in the code. If you insert a new value for this enum anywhere except at the end, this will invalidate your database.

Maybe it's a question of how often you do this versus how often you change the string value of your enum, **but I want to know: is it possible to tell EF to map the string value and not the int value?**

say if I have the following enum:

```
public enum Gender 
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

I want my database to contain the values "Male" or "Female" and not 0 or 1.

Comment: You're right, it's a duplicate. Somehow I missed it, thanks!